# ¿por qué no se replica mi DNS?

Tags: servidor, dns, centos

Tengo un dominio en GoDaddy, la cual tiene la posibilidad de administrar los DNS en la misma plataforma, o te da la posibilidad de configurar tu propio servidor DNS.

He configurado en mi casa (con IP pública dinámica) un servidor DNS en CentOS, he hecho el port forwarding necesario con el puerto 53. Todo aparentemente está funcionando, ya que si hago un **NSLOOKUP www.google.com [mi ip pública]** me responde sin problemas.

El problema que tengo es que no logo entender, por qué cuando intento registrar mi servidor en GoDaddy con el nombre **ns1.[mi dominio].com** no lo reconoce.

He pensado que puede ser por mi IP pública dinámica, o también está la posibilidad que no entienda bien el funcionamiento del DNS en si.

```
$TTL 3H
@       SOA     ns1.[mi dominio].com wlopez@[mi dominio].com. (1480678362 1H 10M 1D 1H)

@       IN      NS      ns1.[mi dominio].com.

@       IN      A       [mi ip pública]
ns1     IN      A       [mi ip pública]
www     IN      A       [mi ip pública]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que principalmente el DNS es para resolver nombres... por lo que si tu pones un nombre no sabrá resolverlo, deberás ya sea en /etc/hosts poner tu ip pública (cambiarla cada vez que se actualice), o en la configuración poner tu ip... Así como también los DNS suelen tener un retardo en replicarse, a veces he tardado hasta 2 días en que aparezca

Comment: El administrador de DNS de GoDaddy solo me permite colocar un FQDN no una IP :(

Comment: y si te haces una ddns? Asi conviertes tu ip en una fqdn.prueba con No-IP o con cualquiera de los muchos servicios que hay.

Answer (score 1):

Esos registros que intentas configurar son a nivel de configuración DNS raíz y no de la configuración de tu servidor `DNS`.

Sigue estos pasos para configurar lo que quieres:

- En el panel de configuración de dominios DNS de Godaddy, dentro de la opción "Dominios > Todos los dominios", pulsa en la rueda dentada y luego en "Administrar DNS".
- En la parte inferior, donde pone "Funciones avanzadas", pulsa en "Nombres de host".
- Pulsa en "Agregar" y agrega una pareja Host / Dirección IP (por ejemplo, `ns1.[mi dominio].com`).

Ahora ya puedes agregar `ns1.[mi dominio].com` como servidor DNS en tu dominio.

Ten en cuenta que la propagación de cambios de `whois` en los dominios puede tardar varias horas o días en propagarse entre los [servidores raíz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_ra%C3%ADz).

Ten en cuenta que los datos que se encuentran mediante la herramienta `whois` en un dominio puede no coincidir con lo que devuelva una consulta DNS a un servidor DNS de ese dominio (aunque lo ideal sería que coincidieran).

Ejemplo:

```
$ whois google.com | grep "^Name Server"
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns2.google.com
Name Server: ns1.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com
$ whois ns1.google.com | grep -i -A 1 "NS1.GOOGLE.COM$"
   Server Name: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
   IP Address: 216.239.32.10
$ dig +short ns1.google.com
216.239.32.10
```

Como puedes ver `ns1.google.com` vale `ns1.google.com` a nivel de `whois` (la información que replican los servidores raíz) y a nivel de lo que responde sus servidores DNS.

PD: Es muy importante que, debido a los tiempos de propagación de los cambios de configuración en los servidores raíz, uses una dirección IP estática.

Es probable que tu dominio se quede sin servicio durante un buen tiempo si no dispones de un DNS de backup con IP estática que pueda atender las consultas mientras cambias de nuevo la IP cuando te cambie.

Por este motivo te desaconsejo encarecidamente que montes un servidor DNS asociado a un registro raíz de tu dominio sobre una IP dinámica.